# Can pace.js loader be applied to single div?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am looking to add pace.js loading bar to a specific DIV tag..  Is it possible to do so? If yes guide me to show bar for 5 seconds and then show mycode

I want pace loader to show for 5 seconds before this game code shows game

Answer (score 0):

**For your first question:**

You have an option in pace.js for telling wich element pace should show up:

```
    window.paceOptions = {
        target: '#IdOfYourDiv'
    };
```

**For the rest:**

Please show the code you already wrote or tried if you want more help, provide an example. Without it it's hard to help you.

Comment: can i get any help?